# Comparison of beam divergence between laser diode and DPSS laser

Tags: optics, lasers, photonics

I'm currently comparing a pulsed laser diode and a pulsed DPSS laser. For the DPSS laser, the beam divergence is listed as "beam divergence (80% of total energy): $<4 \text{mr}$". The laser diode is said to already be collimated, and has a beam divergence angle of "$\theta_\perp$: $\le 10^\circ$" and "$\theta_\parallel \le 12^\circ$". I know that plain laser diodes have more divergent beams than DPSS lasers, but I want to understand the differences here and whether I can lower the beam divergence of the laser diode to be closer to the DPSS laser. What is meant by "beam divergence (80% of total energy)"? And what is meant by a beam divergence angle of "$\theta_\perp$: $\le 10^\circ$" and "$\theta_\parallel \le 12^\circ$"? Furthermore, how do I compare "beam divergence (80% of total energy): $<4 \text{mr}$" to a divergence angle of "$\theta_\perp$: $\le 10^\circ$" and "$\theta_\parallel \le 12^\circ$"? And, lastly, how can I decrease the beam divergence of the LD so that it is closer to the DPSSL? The experiment is over relatively short distances (varying between 10-100cm).

---

### EDIT

[This](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/US%20Lasers%20PDFs/D6505I.pdf) datasheet seems to have the same parameters.